# Programmatically upload synonyms to google search api using java

Tags: authorization, google-api, google-search-api, synonym

I'm having issues figuring out how to programmatically upload synonyms to the google search api from my server using java.

**1. The Authorization**: The description of how to do a server to google api is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). Where can I find a simple example of this using java?

**2. Upload synonyms**: I have created the xml to be uploaded, explained [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api). I am not able to see how I actually upload this to the google-api. Is there an example of how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. The Authorization**

```
    public static String getAuthorizationToken() throws IOException, HttpException{
      PostMethod method = new PostMethod("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
      method.addParameter("accountType", "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE");
      method.addParameter("Email", "my@gmail.com");
      method.addParameter("Passwd", "myPassword");
      method.addParameter("service", "cprose");
      method.addParameter("source", "mySource");
      String response = executeMethodAsString(method);
      return retrieveAuthFromResponse(response);
    }
```

**2. Upload synonym**

```
    public static String updateSynonyms(String authToken, String xml) throws HttpException, IOException{

        PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://www.google.com/cse/api/default/synonyms/abcdefg1234");
        method.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        method.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + authToken);
        RequestEntity entitiy = new StringRequestEntity(xml, "text/xml", "utf-8");
        method.setRequestEntity(entitiy);
        return executeMethodAsString(method);
    }
```